# Group same chars with and without space regardless of case

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, preprocessor

I have dataset that contains car types entered by users with values like: `1.6TDI, 1.6 TDI, 2.0TDI, 2,0 TDI, 3.0BlueTech, 3,0 blue tech` and so on..
I need a to equalize those values.

I would put them all in uppercase for starters and replace `,` with `.` 
but I don't know how to check for same ascii chars and numbers order regardless of spaces and group them under one value.

If I replace spaces for nothing than name of the model would look ugly. Idea is to use value which has most number of occurrences and turn other values into that value.

Any ideas are more than welcome...I don't need full code, good pointers would suffice.

**Explanation**

Idea is to find one true value like 1.6 TDI and equalize all other appearances with that one.

Comment: Equalize them after what?

Comment: Hello Harvey! Maybe you can compare the uppdercase-nospaces strings without actually converting of modifying them?

Comment: do you have a standard list to compare the values against?

Comment: @Bogdan Doicin I've added explanation

Comment: @Datanovice  Idea is to use value which has most number of occurrences and turn other values into that value. In other words there is not list, although that seems like good idea. I would still think it's simpler just to use most occurring value.

Comment: make take the top N of the most recurring values then fix those manually if there aren't too many then you just use a distance matching algorithm if your data isn't to large. if not the idea below is pretty good

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
df['cars'] = df['cars'].str.upper().str.replace(',','.').str.replace(' ','')
```

**Input**

```
           cars     val
0   1.6TDI          1
1   1.6 TDI         2
2   2.0TDI          3
3   2,0 TDI         3
4   3.0BlueTech     5
5   3,0 blue tech   4
```

**Output**

```
           cars     val
0   1.6TDI          1
1   1.6TDI          2
2   2.0TDI          3
3   2.0TDI          3
4   3.0BLUETECH     5
5   3.0BLUETECH     4
```

You can do `groupby` functions without even converting the column like so

```
df.groupby(df['cars'].str.upper().str.replace(',','.').str.replace(' ',''))['val'].sum().reset_index(name='Sum')
```

**Result**

```
           cars     Sum
0   1.6TDI          3
1   2.0TDI          6
2   3.0BLUETECH     9
```

Comment: That's exactly what I already had in mind. Problem is that those names would be displayed in front-end application. As I said :  Idea is to use value which has most number of occurrences and turn other values into that value.